# how do i print to a a CSV file from different inputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

How do I change this to print to a CSV file instead of a text document.

```
name = billy
score = 69

f.write('Name: %s || Score: %i\n' % (name, score))
```

Comment: What do you mean, "instead of a text document"? Change || to ,?

Comment: [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) *is* text.

Comment: change `with open("my-text.txt", "w") as f:` to `with open("my-text.csv", "w") as f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data in a dictionary:

```
>>> player = {'name': 'Pete',
              'score': -10}
```

You can write it as you currently are:

```
>>> f.write('Name: {name} || Score: {score}\n'.format(player))
```

If you use [**`csv.DictWriter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
>>> writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=player.keys())
>>> writer.writeheader()
>>> writer.writerow(player)
```

Comment: Does this solution write the users name with the score into the CSV file?

Comment: @Billy yes, it does.